# Insert existing PDF at position in PrawnPdf created PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I am creating a one page PDF with PrawnPDF in ruby (Rails). I want to insert and existing PDF in the top of the pdf at certain position in the PDF I am creating with PrawnPDF.
This is dooable with an Image but would be good if possible with PDF.
Anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with Prawn, but the combine_pdf gem allows you to merge pdf documents and if you really need to sandwich something in the middle, you could create partial files and merge them in the order you need.

From the doc of https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file1.pdf") # one way to combine, very fast.
pdf << CombinePDF.load("file2.pdf")
pdf.save "combined.pdf"
```